# MySQL INNER JOIN - столбец 'id' в field list задан неоднозначно

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть запрос:

```sql
SELECT
    `id`, `group_id`, `option_id`, `media_id`
FROM
    `s_articles` AS `articles`
INNER JOIN `s_article_configurator_set_group_relations` `set_groups` ON
    `articles`.`configurator_set_id` = `set_groups`.`set_id`
INNER JOIN `s_article_configurator_set_option_relations` `set_options` ON
    `articles`.`configurator_set_id` = `set_options`.`set_id`
RIGHT JOIN `s_articles_img` ON
    `articles`.`id` = (
    SELECT
        `articleID`
    FROM
        `s_articles_img`
    WHERE
        `articleID` IS NOT NULL);
```

При выполнении выводится ошибка:

```
Столбец 'id' в field list задан неоднозначно
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените

```sql
SELECT `id`, `group_id`, `option_id`, `media_id`
```

на

```sql
SELECT `table_name.id`, `group_id`, `option_id`, `media_id`
```

А еще лучше при `INNER JOIN` всегда писать так:

```sql
SELECT `table_name.id`, `table_name.group_id`, `table_name.option_id` ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Предположительно, столбец `id` есть в нескольких таблицах и, соответственно, при данном запросе непонятно какой брать. Поэтому следует это указать явно, как и другие поля тоже:

```sql
SELECT
    NEEDED_TABLE_NAME.`id`,
    NEEDED_TABLE_NAME.`group_id`,
    NEEDED_TABLE_NAME.`option_id`,
    NEEDED_TABLE_NAME.`media_id`
```

Comment: Простите но ведь написано articles.id

Comment: `SELECT \`id\`, \`group_id\`, \`option_id\`, \`media_id\`` - где?

Comment: а понятно спасибо )